# tensorflow lite models for android and instructions

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js, google-codelab

I am trying to follow instructions here to generate models for android.
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/gesture_classification/ml

But when I try to run all commands in codelabs it asks for model.json and the binary weights file model-weights.bin files to upload. Not sure what this means.

If I skip this step second last step failes

```
No such file or directory: 'model.json'
```

Where can I find these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first use the gesture classification web app to generate the TensorFlow.js model trained by your gestures.
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/gesture_classification/web

Once the model is trained from the web app, you can download files like `model.json` and `model-weights.bin` which are needed in other steps.

Comment: amazing thanks. Any idea of Hand tracking models? I tried media pipes but its so hard to setup on windows.

Comment: I don't know of any other popular hand tracking models either. If there are setup issues with on windows, you should probably ask a new question specifically about those, or file a bug to the mediapipe github repository.